# Ruby on rails: How to remove rails associations on the fly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find, associations

I need to remove a relationship between two tables before doing a search in specific.

I have 2 tables: Users and Projects. Users has many projects. When rails search for users it also search for all his projects, but in this query, i do not need the information about the projects.

How do I remove this relationship before making the search for the rails fetch only users?

I'm currently using the following query:

```
User.where("username LIKE '%q%' ")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rails shouldn't automatically search for all the user's projects unless you specifically include that in your query. Can you show the SQL logs where you see that the Projects are being searched? Also, you should do `User.where("username LIKE ?", '%q%')` instead.

Comment: Leo is right. That's not how Rails works.

Comment: Here are the log from a query searching for my name in the application. http://pastebin.com/BDDaQWJW

Comment: Do you have `default scope` in the `User` model?